# Retrieving table data using Selenium WebDriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Sorry I am still new to c# and selenium programming.

I am in the process of automating an application that contains a dynamic table. The table consists of 4 columns, 3 columns contain data and 1 column contains 2 buttons for each row.

When writing my Selenium test I want to pass in a string of 'Username', then have some smart code to retrieve data from the table and match against the passed in String. Once found then I want it to go across the row and select either of the 2 buttons on that row.

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>UserName_Data</td>
    <td>Email_data</td>
    <td>IsDeactivated</>
    <td>[blank]</td>
        <a class="xxx" title="Edit User Account" href="xxx"/>
        <a class="xxx" title="Deactivate User" href="xxx"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>UserName_Data</td>
    <td>Email_data</td>
    <td>IsDeactivated</>
    <td>[blank]</td>
        <a class="xxx" title="Edit User Account" href="xxx"/>
        <a class="xxx" title="Deactivate User" href="xxx"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>UserName_Data</td>
    <td>Email_data</td>
    <td>IsDeactivated</>
    <td>[blank]</td>
        <a class="xxx" title="Edit User Account" href="xxx"/>
        <a class="xxx" title="Deactivate User" href="xxx"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>


[TestMethod]
        public void NavigateToEditManageUsers()
        {
            ManageUsersPage.GoTo();
            ManageUsersPage.EditUser(Bill);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the [blank] td from your example for the purpose of my answer because you described the `<a>` tags being in the 4th column:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>UserName_Data</td>
    <td>Email_data</td>
    <td>IsDeactivated</td>
    <td>
        <a class="xxx" title="Edit User Account" href="xxx"/>
        <a class="xxx" title="Deactivate User" href="xxx"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bill</td>
    <td>Email_data</td>
    <td>IsDeactivated</td>
    <td>
        <a class="xxx" title="Edit User Account" href="xxx"/>
        <a class="xxx" title="Deactivate User" href="xxx"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>UserName_Data</td>
    <td>Email_data</td>
    <td>IsDeactivated</td>
    <td>
        <a class="xxx" title="Edit User Account" href="xxx"/>
        <a class="xxx" title="Deactivate User" href="xxx"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The following will find the second row containing the username "Bill" and then get the first `<a>` tag:

```
//table/tbody/tr[td[1] = "Bill"]/td[4]/a
```

Here is an implementation in C#:

```
public class ManageUsersPage
{
    public static void GoTo()
    {
        // Loads page
    }

    public static void EditUserAccount(string username)
    {
        Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr[td[1] = '" + username + "']/td[4]/a[1]")).Click();
    }

    public static void DeactivateUser(string username)
    {
        Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr[td[1] = '" + username + "']/td[4]/a[2]")).Click();
    }

}

[TestMethod]
public void NavigateToEditManageUsers()
{
    ManageUsersPage.GoTo();
    ManageUsersPage.EditUserAccount("Bill");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, as this table is dynamic and bill is likely to appear down the table due to other users being added, how could i get this scenario to work if I pass in a String of 'Bill'

Comment: Hey Dulku, I'm not completely sure I understand your question. The XPath in my answer will return the correct row (the one where the username is Bill) even if that row is the last one in the table. I've added 2 examples in C# of how you could achieve clicking either `<a>` tags in the desired row.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for the TableDriver extension to .NET WebDriver (https://github.com/jkindwall/TableDriver.NET).  In the above example, it could be used like this:

```cs
public void UserAction(string username, string action)
{
    Table table = Table.CreateWithNoHeaders(driver.FindElement(By.TagName("table")), 0); // Assumes this is the only table on the page.
    TableCell cell = table.FindCell($"0={username}", 3)
    if (action == "edit")
    {
        cell.Element.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[title='Edit User Account'")).Click();
    }
    else if (action == "deactivate")
    {
        cell.Element.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[title='Deactivate User'")).Click();
    }
}
```